# list of objects validation

Tags: json, validation, grails

Hi I'm trying to validate an object with a list of objects within it. Root instance comes from a JSON client file.

I've created something like this

```
@Validateable
class Book {
    String title
    List authors
    static hasMany = [authors : Authors]

    static constraints = {
        authors(nullable:false,validator: { recipients ->
            recipients.every { it.validate() }
        } )     
    }
}

@Validateable
class Author {
    String name
    Integer property

        static constraints = {
        name(nullable:false)    
        property((nullable:false, blank: false))    
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to validate it in the controller this way:

```
class BookController {

def manageBook(Book book){
    if (book.validate()) {
        //Do my stuff
    }else{
        // return error
    }
}
}
```

But it doesn't work at all, and I see this error in the console:

```
| Error 2012-05-25 11:26:34,014 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [POST] /BookApp/rest/bookApp/manageBook
No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject.validate() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: wait(), values(). Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject.validate() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: wait(), values()
   Line | Method
->>  17 | doCall  in dataskaterserver.DeviceSeenWifiData$__clinit__closure1_closure2_closure3
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . . in     ''
^   680 | run     in java.lang.Thread
```

Could anyone help me, please..?

Comment: do you have configured `parseRequest: true` for this url mapping?

Comment: Yes, I've already define parseRequest:true. 
I've this in the url mapping:


  "/rest/$controller/manageBook"(parseRequest:true){
   action = [POST: "manageBook"]
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it was on the documentation... http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html#validationNonDomainAndCommandObjectClasses

Registering Validateable Classes
If a class is not marked with Validateable, it may still be made validateable by the framework. The steps required to do this are to define the static constraints property in the class (as described above) and then telling the framework about the class by assigning a value to the grails.validateable.classes property in Config.groovy@:

```
grails.validateable.classes = [com.mycompany.myapp.User, com.mycompany.dto.Account]
```